# Mostrar imgenes´segun elvalor de una variable

Tags: imagen

Muy buenas. Soy nuevo por aquí y es el primer contacto que tengo con HTML y sin problema estoy utilizando los módulos wifi esp8266, pero el problema se surge con HTML por que no he utilizado nunca.
Tofo funciona bien, pero quiero visualizar una imagen u otro en función del valor de la variable VeranoInvierno.
Si pongo <img src = "sun"... ó <img scr = "snow".... veo una u otra imagen y además los otras variables también aparecen bien.
He intentando incluir un script para obtener valor de la variable VeranoInvierno que quiero que cambie la imagen y aparentemente obtengo el valor, pero ya no sé enlazar el script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ESP8266 Web Server</title>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<!-- 
<script>

<span id="VeranoInvierno">%VERANOINVIERNO%</span>   
    if(VeranoInvierno == "1"){
        img.src = "sun";
    }
    else{
        img.src = "snow";
    }
 }
</script>
-->
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Medidor de Energía V4.0</h1>
  <p>GPIO state<strong> %STATE%</strong></p>
  <p>
    <a href="/on"><button class="button">ON</button></a>
    <a href="/off"><button class="button button2">OFF</button></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="sensor-labels">Temperatura</span>  <!-- El texto que se verá en la página-->
    <span id="Temperatura">%TEMPERATURA%</span>     <!-- 1: Valor que viene -->
    <sup class="units">&deg;C</sup>

      <!-- ************************ -->
  <img src= "snow" />  <!-- Quiero que aparezca una imagen según el valor de VaranoInvierno  -->
      <!-- ************************ -->      
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

He mirado muchos ejemplos y ninguno se adapta a lo que necesito, todos ellos son bastante más complicados de lo que necesito, porque son botones que cambian la imagen al pulsar o cosas parecidas.
Después de muchas horas para entender un poquito de qué va todo esto (que no se parece en nada a los lenguajes como el "C" o similares) me he decidido a hacer la pregunta por si alguien tiene la amabilidad de ayudarme con un empujoncito.

Comment: ¿Dónde exactamente tienes el valor para determinar si es verano o invierno?

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes agregar in ID a tu imagen para enlazar esa variable al script.. intenta haciendo esto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ESP8266 Web Server</title>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Medidor de Energía V4.0</h1>
  <p>GPIO state<strong> %STATE%</strong></p>
  <p>
    <a href="/on"><button class="button">ON</button></a>
    <a href="/off"><button class="button button2">OFF</button></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="sensor-labels">Temperatura</span>  <!-- El texto que se verá en la página-->
    <span id="Temperatura">30 C</span>     <!-- 1: Valor que viene -->
    <sup class="units">&deg;C</sup>

      <!-- ************************ -->
  <img id='imagen' />  <!-- Quiero que aparezca una imagen según el valor de VaranoInvierno  -->
      <!-- ************************ -->      
  </p>
<script>
  //Aqui obtienes tu ETIQUETA imagen atravez del ID con getElementById
  img=document.getElementById("imagen"); 
  veranoInvierno=1;
    if(VeranoInvierno == "1"){
        //img.setAttrubite cambia el atributo src de la imagen
        img.setAttribute("src", "sun");
    }
    else{
        img.setAttribute("src", "snow");
    }
 }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por las respuestas, quizás con mi empeño en familiarizarme con HTML me he complicado mucho la vida. ¿Por qué hacer que HTML decida qué imagen poner cuando es más sencillo que el firmware envíe la imagen que corresponda?:

```
if(HorarioVerano){
      cliente.on("/sunsnow", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){request->send(SPIFFS, "/sun50.png", "image/png");});  ///sun.png
      cliente.on("/HVeranoInvierno", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){request->send(SPIFFS, "/HVerano50.png", "image/png");}); ///
   }         
  else{
      cliente.on("/sunsnow", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){request->send(SPIFFS, "/snow50.png", "image/png");});     
      cliente.on("/HVeranoInvierno", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){request->send(SPIFFS, "/HInvierno50.png", "image/png");});
  }
```

A medida que vaya teniendo más conocimientos de HTML me podré permitir mayores complicaciones. Reconozco que no es nada fácil interactuar con los programas y HTML, pero poco a poco y con la ayuda de colaboradores tan amables como vosotros seguro que lo consigo.
Muchas gracias de nuevo